# Excel 8 possible results with IF statement based on 3 inputs

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

Is it possible to turn the following result table into an IF statement? If not is there any other way to do this?

[image: Result Table]

I have tried many combinations using IF,AND and OR but i cant seem to get it right!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you have O365 or 2021 you may try SWITCH function. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e  on Concatenated Input 1 , 2 & 3

Comment: I will look into this and post back if Im able to resolve using SWITCH! Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 8 Possibilities

**"No"-Based**

```
=IF(AND(A1>=0.5,A2<>"No"),IF(A3="No","Low Risk","High Risk"),IF(A3="No","No","Re-evaluate"))
```

**"Yes"-Based**

```
=IF(AND(A1>=0.5,A2="Yes"),IF(A3<>"Yes","Low Risk","High Risk"),IF(A3<>"Yes","No","Re-evaluate"))
```

- To remove any confusion when cells are blank, create `Yes-No` dropdowns for *cell inputs 2 and 3* (Data -> Data Validation -> List -> `Yes;No`).

[image]

**The AND Condition**

- If you compare rows `3` and `4` you will notice that if in row `3` there is a `No`, the only one that shouldn't result in `No` is the one in column `F` that should result in `Low Risk` **while its 1st row is greater than or equal `0.5` (`A1>=0.5`) and its 2nd row is `Yes` (`A2="Yes"`) or not `No` (`A2<>"No"`)**.
- Similarly, if in row `3` there is a `Yes`, the only one that shouldn't result in `Re-evaluate` is the one in column `H` that should result in `High Risk`, again, **while its 1st row is greater than or equal `0.5` (`A1>=0.5`) and its 2nd row is `Yes` (`A2="Yes"`) or not `No` (`A2<>"No"`)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have O365 or 2021 you can use SWITCH function with concatenated inputs 1 2 3 & relative referencing to get the results.

Here's a sample. See below screenshot.

[image]

Row 4 is static and only for comparison purposes.
The formula in B5

```
=SWITCH(B1&B2&B3,"<50%NoNo","Result1","<50%YesNo","Result2",">=50%NoNo","Eval1",">50%YesNo","Eval2")
```

This just shows 4 conditions but you will have to extend it to all 8 conditions.

Drag  the formula across intended cells. Every concatenated input B1B2B3, C1C2C3 will be compared against the set conditions and for matching condition the result will be displayed.

This assumes that all 8 conditions are unique.

See if this helps.

Comment: This also works but I will go with the selected awnser since its closer to what I requested. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Filter` function like this:[image]

`A5` contains the formula: =FILTER(B5:I5,(B4:I4=A4)*(A3=B3:I3)*(A2=B2:I2))

The formula takes each value in `A2:A4` and compares it with the rest of the row (`B2:I2`,`B3:I3`,`B4:I4`), and returns the match in `B5:I5`.

If you don't have access to filter then the `INDEX`-`MATCH` combination or possibly `SUMPRODUCT` (as a starting point) could also be used.

Comment: This also works but I will go with the selected awnser since its closer to what I requested. Thanks for the help!